# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{2} \frac{t}{t+i} dt$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_{0}^{2} \frac{t}{t+i} dt$$

I have no idea how to even begin to split this up into real and imaginary parts.  The only thing I can think of is that it might involve the use of natural log? Any help on how to begin would be VERY much appreciated!

Comment: You can learn about $\LaTeX$ [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: On which path are we integrating?

Answer (score 5):

You can multiply numerator and denominator by $t-i$.  That will give you a real denominator, so the real/imaginary split will be easy.

Comment: Oh my gosh, that is so obvious, duh! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Splitting problems into real and imaginary parts usually makes them harder, so usually don't want to do it, unless you are specifically looking for solutions expressed, e.g., in terms of $\arctan$ rather than in terms of $\log$ and are willing to do the extra work.

The simplest evaluation method for this integral is essentially no different than the one you would use to evaluate

$$ \int_{0}^{2} \frac{t}{t-3} \, dt $$

and would involve using logarithms, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

For any complex number $a$,
and ignoring any questions about meaning,
$\int \frac{t}{t+a} dt
=\int \frac{t+a-a}{t+a} dt
=\int \frac{t+a}{t+a} dt-\int \frac{a}{t+a} dt
=\int  dt-a\int \frac{1}{t+a} dt
= x - a \ln(x+a)
$.

For your case,
the result is
$(x - i \ln(x+i)) \big|_0^2
=2 - i \ln(2+i) +i \ln(i)
= 2 - i\ln(2/i+1)
=2 - i\ln(1-2i)
$.

Comment: Is your answer unique?  If not, how would you choose from all the possibilities?

Comment: $\ln$ is multivalued, so I would get the result's real and imaginary parts (which will probably have a $i\pi n$in then) and then consider.

Answer (score 0):

You may take the imaginary part as a vertical axis, and $t$ as real axis, then integrate as if the integrand were a real division.